# Re use the venv that's already created in a given folder

Tags: python-venv

I used to keep my projects in a HDD and recently changed my pc. Now when I try to activate the virtual environment using:

`.\wfa_virtual\Scripts\activate`

it activates the environment but when I try to install a new package using the command:

`pip install --upgrade google-cloud-bigquery`

it gives me error saying:

`Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"f:\yoptima_bcup\yoptima_curr\universaldashboard\workflowautomationnew\wfa_instancebcup\workflow-automation\workflowautomation\wfa_virtual\scripts\python.exe"`

The only change in the folder location is D drive from f drive, how can I let my venv know that the location has been changed?

Edit: I have also tried updating:

`VIRTUAL_ENV="D:\yoptima_bcup\Yoptima_Curr\universalDashboard\workFlowAutomationNew\wfa_instanceBcup\workflow-automation\workFlowAutomation\wfa_venv"`  in `activate` file and also:

`set VIRTUAL_ENV=D:\yoptima_bcup\Yoptima_Curr\universalDashboard\workFlowAutomationNew\wfa_instanceBcup\workflow-automation\workFlowAutomation\wfa_venv`

in `activate.bat` file but no effect.

Comment: Just to be sure... the python interpreter IS still in that folder, right?

Comment: It is inside the venv folder.